# Button OnClick does not work in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, master-pages

I'm working with Bootstrap. I created a master page and the general purpose is to store the input from user in the contact form (name, email, message,...), captcha used also:

```
<!-- Omitted -->
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Name*" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />

<!-- CAPTCHA -->
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" Width="200px"/>
<asp:Image ID="imgCaptcha" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />

<!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" Text="Send Message" CssClass="btn btn-xl" OnClick="submit_Click" />
```

The code inside submit_Click does not work for me:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //Check captcha
    if (Session["captcha"].ToString() != txtCaptcha.Text)
        Response.Write("Invalid Captcha Code");
    else
        Response.Write("Valid Captcha Code");
    FillCapctha();  //Reload text

    //Store input into database
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.name = txtName.Text;
    contact.message = txtMessage.Text;
}
```

Nothing works here. Someone has suggestions? I'll appreciate much!

Comment: What error/exception or message are you getting here and at which point ?

Comment: Did you enter something in `txtName`, or did you leave `txtName` blank when you clicked the button?

Comment: did you inspect html? did you debug code?

Comment: Do the `btnRefresh_Click` event for `btnRefresh` work? What happens when you debug the `submit_Click` event with a breakpoint at the beginning of the method? Does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: I just use firebug, take a look at js and the problem is that the IDs of the textboxes are changed. If I keep using js, the code inside the `submit_Click` does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions :
It looks like you are using jquery validations(required) on page. Check errors using firebug. There is possibility that due to some JS issues(may be bootstrap js) it does not process.